# Error during Sonar runner execution 5.0. "After migrating 3.7.4 to 5.0"

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube-4.5

migrate my database to another scheme.
And migrate from 3.7.4 to 5.0.
So far so perfect.

Now when running scheduled tasks on jenkins, get this error:

```
17:47:35.275 INFO  - Store results in database
17:47:35.275 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.index.MeasurePersister
17:47:35.400 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@41ccdc4d[id=139867,key=7X24:7X24,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-7X24:7X24
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1:42.087s
Final Memory: 33M/815M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to save some measures
    at org.sonar.batch.index.MeasurePersister.persist(MeasurePersister.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.executePersisters(PhaseExecutor.java:163)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:132)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error committing transaction.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.api.database.model.MeasureMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: restricción única (SONAR5.SYS_C0078055) violada

### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.api.database.model.MeasureMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: restricción única (SONAR5.SYS_C0078055) violada

    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:177)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:169)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:61)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.BatchSession.commit(BatchSession.java:177)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.BatchSession.increment(BatchSession.java:214)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.BatchSession.insert(BatchSession.java:134)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.batch.index.MeasurePersister.persist(MeasurePersister.java:71)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.api.database.model.MeasureMapper.insert (batch index #1) failed. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: restricción única (SONAR5.SYS_C0078055) violada

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:114)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.commit(BaseExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.commit(CachingExecutor.java:104)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:174)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: restricción única (SONAR5.SYS_C0078055) violada

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10500)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:103)
    ... 47 more
Build step 'Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**This is an index (SONAR5.SYS_C0078055).**

**CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SONAR5"."SYS_C0078055" ON "SONAR5"."PROJECT_MEASURES" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SONAR5_DATA_S" ;**

**I do not understand the problem of error.
Help.
Thank.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to migrate sequences when changing SQ scheme. Ids for new measures are starting from 1 so that create duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

**these sequences are imported:**

---

```
--  DDL for Sequence ACTION_PLANS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ACTION_PLANS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence ACTIVE_DASHBOARDS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ACTIVE_DASHBOARDS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10082 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence ACTIVE_RULE_PARAMETERS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ACTIVE_RULE_PARAMETERS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10145 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence ACTIVE_RULES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ACTIVE_RULES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 13079 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence ACTIVITIES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ACTIVITIES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10660 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence ANALYSIS_REPORTS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ANALYSIS_REPORTS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence AUTHORS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."AUTHORS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence CHARACTERISTICS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."CHARACTERISTICS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 11484 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence DASHBOARDS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."DASHBOARDS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10069 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence DEPENDENCIES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."DEPENDENCIES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 972500 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence DUPLICATIONS_INDEX_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."DUPLICATIONS_INDEX_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence EVENTS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."EVENTS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 36147 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence FILE_SOURCES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."FILE_SOURCES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 85120 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence GRAPHS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."GRAPHS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence GROUP_ROLES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."GROUP_ROLES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 20653 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence GROUPS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."GROUPS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10006 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence ISSUE_CHANGES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ISSUE_CHANGES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 260350 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence ISSUE_FILTER_FAVOURITES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ISSUE_FILTER_FAVOURITES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence ISSUE_FILTERS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ISSUE_FILTERS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence ISSUES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."ISSUES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1611712 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence LOADED_TEMPLATES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."LOADED_TEMPLATES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10034 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence MANUAL_MEASURES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."MANUAL_MEASURES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10002 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence MEASURE_FILTER_FAVOURITES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."MEASURE_FILTER_FAVOURITES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10086 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence MEASURE_FILTERS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."MEASURE_FILTERS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10088 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence METRICS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."METRICS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10249 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence NOTIFICATIONS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."NOTIFICATIONS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 257944 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence PERM_TEMPLATES_GROUPS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."PERM_TEMPLATES_GROUPS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10023 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence PERM_TEMPLATES_USERS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."PERM_TEMPLATES_USERS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence PERMISSION_TEMPLATES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."PERMISSION_TEMPLATES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10021 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence PROJECT_LINKS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."PROJECT_LINKS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence PROJECT_MEASURES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."PROJECT_MEASURES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 50738651 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence PROJECTS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."PROJECTS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 149618 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence PROPERTIES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."PROPERTIES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 11701 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence QUALITY_GATE_CONDITIONS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."QUALITY_GATE_CONDITIONS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10020 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence QUALITY_GATES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."QUALITY_GATES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10020 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence RESOURCE_INDEX_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."RESOURCE_INDEX_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 2947694 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence RULES_PARAMETERS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."RULES_PARAMETERS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10565 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence RULES_PROFILES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."RULES_PROFILES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10028 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence RULES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."RULES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 13063 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence SEMAPHORES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."SEMAPHORES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 12956 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence SNAPSHOT_DATA_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."SNAPSHOT_DATA_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 328704 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence SNAPSHOTS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."SNAPSHOTS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1479404 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence USER_ROLES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."USER_ROLES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10002 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence USERS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."USERS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10465 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence WIDGET_PROPERTIES_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."WIDGET_PROPERTIES_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10296 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence WIDGETS_SEQ
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SONAR5"."WIDGETS_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10242 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

**I'm thinking of redoing everything again.
But nose if I'll have the same result.**

Comment: OK, but are sequence current values restored or reset to zero when doing the import? What is currval of each sequence?

Comment: thanks for the help, the problem is that the sequence was wrong with the maximum number.